# How to extract embedded Value from comboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, combobox, key-value-observing

I'm populating my combobox with an underlying value and a display value this way:

```
Dictionary<int, string> Platypi = duckBillData.GetPlatypiVals();
comboBoxPlatypus.DataSource = new BindingSource(Platypi, null);
comboBoxPlatypus.ValueMember = "Key";
comboBoxPlatypus.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

Now I want to extract the ValueMember of the selected item. How do I do that? None of the "obvious" things seem to have a "ValueMember"...I've tried:

```
int id = comboBoxPlatypus.ValueMember;
int id = comboBoxPlatypus.SelectedIndex. <-- no "ValueMember" here...
int id = comboBoxPlatypus.SelectedItem. <-- no "ValueMember" here...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueMember` tells the combo box which property of your original collection to *bind* to, it is not the bound object itself.  `SelectedItem` should contain your resulting value.  You just need to cast it to the correct type, which in this case is your `int` key.

```
int id = (int) comboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Actually, with this: int callFlowID = (int)comboBoxCallFlow.SelectedItem;
I get, "System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: Is the key on your dictionary (or whatever you specified as ValueMember) still an int?

Comment: This also fails:

int callFlowID = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxCallFlow.ValueMember);

...the value of ValueMember is "Key" ...???

Comment: Right, so ValueMember is a `string` that tells winforms which property of your collection to use as the value when constructing the combo box.  It only specifies what property contains the value, not the value itself, and is not an `int`.  `SelectedItem` is definitely what you want, but you need to make sure it has the right type.

Comment: The SelectedItem does contain the vals that I want {[1, Bla]} (I want the "1" in this case), but casting it to (int) still fails. The dictionary contains a pair of int,string.

Comment: It looks like your SelectedItem is a dictionary KeyValuePair.  Try inspecting its type, cast it to the correct type, and then extract the value you need, e.g., `((KeyValuePair) comboBox.SelectedItem).Key` [Note the parentheses around the casted object to get to the Key property.]

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks:
int callFlowID = ((KeyValuePair<int,string>
         comboBoxCallFlow.SelectedItem).Key;

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help!